# Question about exercise 7.5 in TeXbook

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, texbook.tex

Consider this extract from *TeXbook*:

> EXERCISE 7.5
>   Experiment with TEX to see what `\string` does when it is followed by an
>   active character like `~`. (Active characters behave like control sequences, but they are
>   not prefixed by an escape.) What is an easy way to conduct such experiments online?
>   What control sequence could you put after `\string` to obtain the single character
>   token `\ 12` ?

The answer reads:

> If you type ‘`\message{\string~}`’ and ‘`\message{\string\~}`’, TEX responds
>   with ‘`~`’ and ‘`\~`’, respectively.

What was Knuth's flow of reasoning when he tried to use \~ here? I mean, how can we logically deduce from the exercise that we must try \~ when it is told there only about ~?

Further, why the word "therefore" in the next extract is used? I mean, how can we conclude from "`\string\~ experiment`" that we must make `\` an active character? I can understand the relevance of "`\string~`", but why "`\string\~`"?

> To get `\ 12` from \string you therefore need to make
>   backslash an active character.

Besides, it is possible to make it "other" also, which is not mentioned in TeXbook:

```
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=12 /message{/string\}}
```

Incidentally, why catcode changes cannot be put directly to \message, without the need for extra grouping (even with the original Knuth's active character example), i.e. why if we change the original

```
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=13 /message{/string\}}
```

into

```
\message{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=13 /string\}
```

then it stops working?

Comment: Category code changes are assignments and, as such, can only be performed in TeX's "stomach"; `\message{<text>}` simply displays <text> on the terminal, expanding expandable tokens and displaying in symbolic form unexpandable ones.  In your example, for instance, `\\ ` would be expanded, while `\catcode` would be displayed symbolically, _i.e._, as if it had been preceded by `\string`.  Also, after giving to `\ ` the `\catcode` "other", `\string\ ` and just `\ ` are essentially equivalent.  Your other questions are pretty subjective.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get the \ character work as I would like to between backquotes.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti -- go to this question in the meta queue: [Formatting Sand-Box](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/208/579)  it has examples of things that are hard to format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command `\message` is pretty similar to `\write` in its working: it accepts a token list as argument and shows *its expansion* on the terminal; unexpandable tokens are shown by their name, followed by a space if they are control words.

*No* command is *executed*, in particular assignments are not performed. So your try with

```
\message{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=13 /string\}
```

is doomed to failure for a number of reasons.

1. The argument for `\message` must be ended by an explicit right brace which isn't in the code; TeX will continue scanning the input for a `<right brace>` matching the `{` after `\message`, without probably finding one.
2. Even if you type `` \message{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=13 /string\ } `` you don't get what you want, because the category code of `\` is not changed.
3. What you get is due to a, *mmmh*, feature of `plain.tex` that leaves defined `\\` as a macro with a delimited argument; but even if you say `\let\\=\relax` before `\message` what you get on the terminal is just

   ```
   \catcode `/=0 \catcode `\\=13 /string\
   ```

   and after the fact the category code of the backslash is still 0, even if the argument to `\message` doesn't technically form a group.

Note that no `\expandafter` can solve the issue, because it does *expansion*, not *execution*: these are different concepts in TeX and are performed at different stages.

Now why does Knuth compare `\string~` with `\string\~`? Possibly because one might think that `\string` behaves with character tokens in a similar way to alphabetic constants, whereby

```
\char`~
\char`\~
\char126
```

are equivalent. This is not true for `\string`, however.

Why does Knuth say `\` *must* be made active? I don't know; any character code other than 0, 5, 9, 10, 14, 15 would work the same.

So, how do you get a *macro* `\backslashstring` whose expansion is `\`<sub>12</sub>?

There are several ways:

```
\begingroup\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=12 /gdef/backslashstring{\}\endgroup

\begingroup\escapechar=-1 \xdef\backslashstring{\string\\}\endgroup

\begingroup\lccode`?=`\\ \lowercase{\endgroup\def\backslashstring{?}}
```

each using a different idea.

With LuaTeX (version 0.75 or later) one can also do

```
\edef\backslashstring{\Uchar`\\}
```

With XeTeX 0.99992 (available with TeX Live mid June 2015), a further possibility has been added

```
\edef\backslashstring{\Ucharcat`\\ 12}
```

and also the `\Uchar` method works.

Comment: Note that LuaTeX can also do the same as XeTeX here, with the latest LuaTeX providing a mechanism to emulate primitive syntax (see https://github.com/davidcarlisle/utex/blob/master/regression-test.cfg for an implementation).

Comment: @JosephWright This is very interesting, but requires other code for working. When the (pseudo)primitive `\Ucharcat` will be in `luatex.fmt`…

Comment: BTW, another possible for the list of ways to create `\backslashstring` is `\long\def\gobble#1{}\edef\backslashstring{\expandafter\gobble\string\\}` [for completeness :-)]. (I'm assuming a printable non-space escape char: we have some code in `expl3` that will do the same for without such an assumption but it's longer.)

Comment: @JosephWright I wanted to just use primitives, but of course your suggestion is good.

Comment: There's also ``\edef\backslashstring{\Uchar`\\}`` with LuaTeX? (I think, I'm not sure.)

Comment: @Manuel Yes, it works also in XeTeX